# UDP Incorrect checksum triggers repeat request instead of dropping packet

Tags: python, sockets, error-handling, udp

hope you're having a good day.

I am using UDP to send packets of data from a microcontroller to a python server on my PC (I could not get the speeds I needed over TCP).

I want to send a repeat request to the microcontroller if a packet is dropped (assuming this is the easiest method for error correction over UDP)?

I am aware UDP uses checksum and if this is incorrect it will be dropped by the receiver. Is there a flag or equivalent in python socket so that when a packet is dropped, I can ask the microcontroller to send the packet again?

Thanks in advance for your time,
Will

Comment: As the answer mentioned, UDP is unreliable protocol (i.e. It just sends packets and doesn't care if they are received or not). So, if you really need to use UDP, you have to do this mechanism by yourself (i.e. If the packet is dropped in your python server, you should send a predefined UDP packet from server to the microcontroller. In the microcontroller side, when you receive this predefined UDP packet, make it resends the last packet again).

Comment: One other thing, you need to check why the checksum is not correct, is this expected in your application?

Comment: @MohammedOsama yes that is exactly what I need to do! My question is how do I detect that a packet is dropped using python socket?

Comment: The reason checksum would be incorrect is just due the rare occasion where an error occurs whilst transmitting (1 to 0 or 0 to 1). It is not expected to return a faulty checksum

Comment: I don't think this is possible as failed UDP checksum packets are dropped at a low-level in the operating system network stack. Anyway, if you could disable this there's nothing in a UDP packet that would allow the peer to know **which** packet needs to be retransmitted. There's no sequence number for example. You're demanding UDP have the functionality of TCP but it can't.

Answer (score 1):

UDP is an unreliable protocol. It has no mechanism to "ask for sending again" if a packet gets dropped because of the wrong checksum. It has also no mechanism to detect duplicate packets, reordering or lost packets. There is no kind of flag which could be switch on to get a reliable transport based on UDP.

If you need reliable transport either use TCP or implement you own custom reliability layer on top of UDP.

Comment: I am aware it's unreliable, but all I need is socket to tell me: "hey the packet I just received has a wrong checksum". Then I can send a UDP message to the microcontroller to tell it to resend the last buffer (stored in memory).

Comment: @WillPowell: There is such kind of mechanism. The packet is simply discarded. Apart from that it will be more likely that a packet got completely lost compared to getting accidentally modified, so such a feature would have a very limited use.